# How switch keyboard layout once for all open programms?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-layout

When I switch keyboard layout windows switches it for current open program. When I switch among many programs I often get confused what keyboard current program uses. Is there a way to switch keyboard layout once for all open programms?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. If you constantly need to switch config, I suggest setting the one you need most as default, or use one that has all your needs and learn with the fact that it types differently for special characters, such as " requiring to type `"space`.

Do note that you can switch layouts using methods:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>: Switch between keyboard layouts
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>: Switch between keyboard languages

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, you should be able to do this by going to the "Switching input methods" section under "Advanced keyboard settings", then deselecting "Let me use a different input method for each app window".